# Ceiling fan light

Tags: ceiling-fan, light

Out of the blue, my Harbor Breeze ceiling fan light began flashing when the light is on.  Worked fine for many years and nothing was changed - just one day when turned on the lights flash and its been that way for a week.  Checked wiring even though nothing was changed and everything is correct and all connections are tight.  And advice?

Comment: What kind of lightbulb is it? Does the fan have a remote? Or is this a wall switch for the light? Is it a dimmer?

Comment: CFL or LED bulb(s)?